# Kafka broker bytes out are sent in spikes while kafka bytes in come in constantly

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have an HDInsights Kafka broker where I'm processing a lot of data.

While checking Ambari for metrics and stats I see that the bytes are coming in constantly from my producers, however, the bytes are going out in spikes to my consumers.
From the consumers perspective, I see a lot of Partition Revoked, that causes a lot of idle periods. The consumer system is healthy and doing the commits in way less time than the session-timeout. 
The brokers are also with low CPU and Memory usage.

I tried tunning it with a lot of different configs, without success.

Blue shows bytes Out.
Green shows bytes In.
[image: graph](https://ibb.co/Mcsvz1X)[![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3nbV.png)

EDIT:

My consumer config:

```
    consumer-config:
        client-id: "kafka-client"
        group-id-config: "UUID"
        enable-auto-commit: "false"
        auto-commit-interval: "1000"
        heartbeat.interval.ms: "12000"
        session-timeout: "120000"
        max-poll-records: "100"
        auto-offset: "latest"
        max-partition-fetch-bytes: "20000000"
```

Did anyone see this before and can give some tips?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have fetch.min.bytes set in your consumer config?

Comment: Hi A.Dev, thanks for replying.
I actually don't have. Only max.partition.fetch.bytes set to 20Mb

Comment: Can you post your consumer config?

Comment: A.Dev updated with the configs

Comment: may be good idea to show the error message